# Why go to another galaxy?

Tags: interstellar

Was it ever explained why did they decide to go through the black hole and to another galaxy instead of simply going to Mars? Mars is much closer than Saturn and we know much more about it, so they could've started sending people there right away.

Comment: This is a question I've considered myself.  In fact, why didn't they just park their space stations around Mars (or around Earth for that matter) and continue to live in them?  They looked a lot more comfortable than either Mars ***or*** Edmunds.

Comment: Note they can't launch the space stations until they have TARS' data from Gargantua.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Edmunds World may be a bit desolate to begin with, but the settlers will have access to dozens of moons and planets worth of easily accessible resources and mineral assets. In the long run, it's a far better bid than staying in orbit, waiting to get clobbered by the next passing asteroid

Comment: @Richard *".. waiting to get clobbered by the next passing asteroid"*  When did we start talking about the dinosaurs?  As an aside, if the dinosuars had been technological enough to build hundreds of space stations and put them in orbits evenly distributed around a star, then only one station would get clobbered at any particular time.  ;)

Comment: @OrangeDog *"Note they can't launch the space stations until they have TARS' data from Gargantua."*  Yes I did note that.  The point is that once they had the data to (build and) launch the space stations, there were a lot better places to live, and many more options, than on some desert planet (which had a notably different sidereal period) in the outer accretion disk of a black hole!

Comment: Space station isn't big enough. Presumably they want to have children etc.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - This is a bit like asking why people go on holiday when they could just stay at the first service station or live in the car.

Comment: @Richard  *"This is a bit like asking why people go on holiday when they could just stay at the first service station or live in the car."*  Not until the two latter options are **demonstrably better** than the accommodation expected at the end of the journey, as the space stations were.  Let's start with - you could have 24 hr sidereal period.  Then go on to, and low chance of being hit by any parts of any stellar system that was on a trajectory into the accretion disk, or be flipped out of orbit by same, and go into a different orbit that takes you **through** the accretion disk. ..

Comment: @OrangeDog *"Space station isn't big enough."* `</head-desk>` Do they have 'mass production' on your planet?  With the resources of the solar system (even being careful never to visit Earth for fear of blight infection) at our disposal, if we could build one of those things, we could build a million of them.  We could also build them larger where they could be made more efficient and less 'living in a tube' feel.

Comment: You think after the ecological disaster, economic collapse, and euthanasia of entire populations, they can mass produce millions of habitable space stations?

Comment: @OrangeDog *"You think after the ecological disaster, economic collapse, and euthanasia of entire populations, they can mass produce millions of habitable space stations?"*  No, but their **children can** (which is what you were talking about, after all).  And they were able to create enough space stations to house the *entire remaining human population at the time they left.*  Given each or those space stations shown would only be able to support one to a few thousands of people, that implies they already had the ability to manufacture tens of thousands of them..

Comment: The film never says what the remaining human population is, what proportion was rescued, or anything about the other assumptions you're making.

Comment: Terraforming Mars would take so many years in today's technology, human-race would go extinct by the end of the terraforming process. That was the reason (probably, there weren't any mentions of this in the movie) why they wanted to explore Gargantua (wormhole) instead of starting from zero on Mars. It was their last hope, movie shows it was already their last chance at survival. [Source_1](https://www.quora.com/How-long-would-it-take-to-terraform-Mars), [Source_2](http://www.science20.com/robert_inventor/trouble_with_terraforming_mars-126407).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The film's [official novelisation](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Interstellar-The-Official-Movie-Novelization/dp/1783293691) speaks to this issue. Bluntly, Mars is simply too hard for them to colonise through classical (rocket-propelled) means and by the point that humanity has mastered gravity control, courtesy of Coop and his crew, there are already better and easier candidates that they can access through the wormhole, starting with Edmunds World, a world with a breathable atmosphere and ready access to 12 whole planets worth of minerals and resources:

> Mars had been an object of fascination from the earliest days of
> modern astronomy, in part because it seemed so Earthlike.
>
> Whole civilizations had risen on the red planet—in the imaginations of
> Lowell, Wells, Weinbaum, Burroughs, and so many other famous authors.
> Those civilizations had all fallen when the first robotic landers
> reported the dull truth. **If Mars had ever been a place habitable by
> human beings—or anything like them—it had been a very long time ago.**
> And if there was life there now, it was **hiding itself very, very well.
> Which is why they had left it behind.**
>
> Mars wasn’t going to be
> humanity’s new home, any more than the Moon was.

Answer (score 10):

Lexible has done an excellent job already of explaining why we wouldn't go to Mars.  (To repeat this in my own words, they wouldn't be looking for a planet with *poorer biological prospects* than their Earth — and Mars today would certainly have poorer prospects — but rather a planet that would be similar to a *healthy* Earth.)

But the Mars issue seems to be secondary to the actual question:

## Why did they have to leave the galaxy?

First of all, "Goldilocks planets" are not so uncommon, even within our galaxy.  According to the most recent NASA studies, there could be as many as 8.8 billion solar systems in our own galaxy with Earth-like planets:

> Space is vast, but it may not be so lonely after all: A study finds the Milky Way is teeming with billions of planets that are about the size of Earth, orbit stars just like our sun, and exist in the Goldilocks zone — not too hot and not too cold for life....
>
> For perspective, that's more Earth-like planets than there are people on Earth.
>
> As for what it says about the odds that there is life somewhere out there, it means "**just in our Milky Way galaxy alone, that's 8.8 billion throws of the biological dice**," said study co-author Geoff Marcy, a longtime planet hunter from the University of California at Berkeley.

([Source](http://www.cbc.ca/news/technology/billions-of-earth-like-planets-in-milky-way-study-1.2356237))

Note that this estimate was publicly available before principal filming began on *Interstellar* (but not necessarily before the final script was completed).

In any case, assuming that our galaxy *does contain an ample selection of at least marginally Earth-like planets*, it would seem that the future humans who created the wormhole had decided that none of the possibly 8.8 billion candidates were suitable for some reason or other.

The reason why they were not suitable may have had nothing to do with their biological prospects.  Rather, it seems that the future humans wanted to point us to a particular combination: **an Earth-like planet in orbit of a giant rotating black hole.**  This effectively kills two birds with one stone: it gives us a habitable planet and the data necessary to solve the "gravity problem" (care of the black hole), which would be necessary for moving the surviving Earth population to their new home, i.e. the realization of "Plan A".

They pointed the humans of Coop's time to a galaxy that *did* have a suitable combo — although he and Brand and the others would have to figure out which of the twelve planets at the other end of the wormhole were most suitable.

(Acknowledgements to **@AndrewThompson**, **@Yasskier**, **@JaneS**, and **@Hypnosifl** for useful discussions.)

Comment: I thought they (who opened the worm hole from the future) opened the worm hole to Gargantua because when they consulted the history books, that's exactly where the humans went..

Comment: Lexible is not a he.

Comment: @Lexible : I'm sorry, I did worry about that when writing this.  (I even went to your profile and found that you were *simply shrouded in mystery*.)  I've fixed this (through the addition of further mystery).... :-)

Comment: Just to add to your answer: to colonize the space the current humans had to learn the gravity control by going into the black hole. While there are plenty Goldilock planets in our galaxy, I doubt there are so many surrounding such massive black holes.

Comment: @Yasskier : Indeed, very good point.

Comment: I thought it was because of the close proximity of potentially habitable planets to a black hole that could provide the necessary data.  The black hole needed to be close enough to the habitable "Plan B" candidates without spending decades travelling to them.  I'm not sure how common this configuration would be, but the future humans must have decided this was the best option.

Comment: "(If our galaxy had one, then the spacetime-bulk-travelling future humans would have pointed us to it instead.)" What's the logic behind this? If the bulk beings found it just as easy to open a portal to another galaxy as to a different star in ours, why would they have any particular preference for a nearer location? Also, they may not have just been looking for a habitable planet, but one orbiting a giant black hole so a human could fall in and gain the information needed to "solve gravity".

Comment: @Hypnosifl: There's no evidence, at least going by the film alone, that it is "just as easy to open a portal to another galaxy as to a different star in ours".  But the point about gathering data from the rotating black hole is a very good one that I overlooked last night when typing up my answer (I got fixated on the fact that Goldilocks planets are more common than some might think).  This is a work in progress.  Expect edits shortly.  Thanks.  :-)

Comment: @Hypnosifl: But one think I was thinking when typing up the original answer (part of my logic, I suppose) is that if it *were* easy for them to open up such wormholes, why not open up two, one to a black hole capable of supplying the necessary data and another to a Goldilocks planet.  There's no need for the planet(s) to be orbiting the black hole, *if* it is easy to open up such wormholes...in any case, working on revisions now.

Comment: @JaneS : Thanks --- great points.  See also my responses to Hypnosifl.

Comment: The bulk beings may not assume humanity will survive long enough (or have the resources) to launch two major expeditions through two different wormholes (or that if they first happen to launch an expedition through the wormhole leading to the habitable planet, that they will bother launching a second). Also, they may not assume humans will voluntarily choose to dive into the black hole, and having the habitable planet in the same system as the black hole increases the chances of an "accident".

Comment: @Hypnosifl : That makes sense.  I didn't actually put the one vs. two wormhole discussion into my latest revisions; it was just something that came up in my thinking earlier.

Comment: This answer indirectly demands an explanation for the Fermi Paradox. The film doesn't touch this (it can't, given the characters' relatively limited information), but whatever causes the Fermi Paradox despite the theoretical abundance of "goldilocks planets" may be a reason for humanity's survival to require *escape*, not mere relocation. Also, if you can time travel and open wormholes, "ten galaxies to the east" is perhaps effectively equivalent to "next planet over". Ultimately, there is only so much one telling of a complex story can explain out of context.

Answer (score 6):

Mars is inhospitable to macro-cellular life. The expedition beyond the wormhole is a crap-shoot (with twelve chances) to find a *hospitable* planet... one that has water, [a breathable atmosphere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102094/the-atmosphere-and-landscape-of-edmunds), and both sunlight and temperatures in or near the [Goldilocks Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumstellar_habitable_zone). Mars is on the near side of failure (but still failure) for water, does not have anything approaching a breathable atmosphere, is extraordinarily cold, and has questionable amounts of sunlight to support enough [primary photosynthetic production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_production) to feed an herbivorous population.

Space is even worse on all fronts, with the exception of available sunlight. That's why we don't find living things there in the abundance we find them on our planet.

Comment: *"Space is even worse on all fronts.."*  [This](https://skepticalswedishscientists.files.wordpress.com/2015/04/interstellar-film-cooper-station-cylindrical-spinning-space-colony.jpg) looks quite hospitable to me..

Comment: @AndrewThompson Such habitats are strictly more costly and more dangerous than (a) and alternate habitable planet, and (b) habitable Earth (i.e. pre-blight).

Comment: *"Such habitats are .. more dangerous.."*  Tsunami, Earthquake (Marsquake, Edmundsquake, call it what you will), cyclone, tornado..  You were saying?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I grew up in California, yo: earthquakes aren't as dangerous as space (*yes*, there are dangers, including quakes). Here's a clue: where do you find life? As to floating habitats: stray comet? Radiation shielding for cosmic rays? Space is just more dangerous for us.

Comment: *"..where do you find life?"*  Humans aren't just (dumb) life.  We have **technology.**  *"As to floating habitats: stray comet?"* It's easier to alter the orbit of a space habitat than a planet.  And people that bring that up seem to forget it affects planets as well, and probably worse given the localized nature of them, and their tendency to *attract* other objects. *"Radiation shielding for cosmic rays?"*  .. Umm.. you'd use radiation shielding for that.  It could take many forms. It would be easier to do for a large structure than a typical spacecraft or current day space station.

Answer (score 2):

The humans of the future [(apparently from Plan B)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72319/who-exactly-constructed-the-tesseract-room-in-interstellar) built the wormhole from the Solar System to Gargantua so the humans on Earth could obtain the quantum data necessary to solve the gravity equation and then leave Earth en masse.

Gargantua is a rare type of black hole with an event horizon you can cross without being ripped apart.  As Romilly states:

> Gargantua's an older, spinning black hole. It has what we call a gentle singularity...They're hardly gentle, but their tidal gravity is quick enough that something crossing the horizon fast might survive...

Being rare, they had to travel a long way to find such a black hole.

Mars obviously would not have the quantum data needed.